# Match the x that is not escaped by another x or \ in .NET

Tags: .net, regex, split

In `.NET`, I need to split a string using the char `x` that is **not escaped by itself nor by a `\`**

In `PCRE`, I could match that specific x using RegEx verbs for example: `[x\\]x(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|x` - [**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/dJ1fJ4/2)

But I could not figure out a way to do it in `.NET`

Here's some examples:

```
ie: in xxx => match the last x
    in axa => match the one x
    in xx => match NONE
    in xxxx => match NONE
    in xx\x => match NONE
    in xxx\x => match the 3rd x only
    in \xxx => match NONE
    Xs can be from 1 to 100 :-/
```

**Edit 1:** BTW, [here's the RegEx quick reference for `.NET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Edit 2:**

As I said, I want to split the string at the "non escaped x"... or in other words, I want to capture the parts of the string separated by that x. For example:

```
aaaxxxbbbxcccxdddxxeee => I should capture:  aaaxx
     ^   ^   ^                               bbb
     SPLIT HERE                              ccc
                                             dddxxeee
```

**Edit 3:**

I finally made this: `((?:(?:[^x\\]|\\[^x])+(?:[x\\]x)*|(?:[x\\]x)+)+)` - [**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/dM4bB8/4)

<strike>Could it be optimised more ? If yes, post it as an answer and i'll accept it (if it really adds something)</strike>

**Edit 4:** 
Solved, thanks to [Tim Pietzcker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26664737/1519058)

Comment: If one is doing a regex replace there is an option which I might provide that is unique to .Net. To recommend that I would need to know what the XXX gets changed to, such as XXY and other combinations. Can you provide the result beyond just the match condition?

Comment: @OmegaMan, check my last edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a much simpler way. Don't use `Split()`, use `Matches()`:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(?>[^\\x]+|[\\x]x)+");
allMatchResults = regexObj.Matches(subjectString);
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/xC3nG9/1).

**Explanation:**

```
(?>       # Start an atomic group (to avoid backtracking)
 [^\\x]+  # Either match any number of characters except backslashes or x
|         # or
 [\\x]x   # match \x or xx
)+        # Repeat as necessary
```

In case there could also be other backslash escapes besides `\x`, use

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(?>[^\\x]+|xx|\\.)+");
```

Comment: Amazing, it was that simple xD   Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome. It's often easier to create a regex that matches the stuff between the matches that you actually want - so it's always worth a thought whether splitting or matching is simpler to do.

Comment: impressive, I suggest modifying the pattern to `((?>[^\\x]+|[\\x]x|\\(?!x))+)` so not to skip a `\ ` not followed by `x` http://regex101.com/r/xC3nG9/4

Comment: @alphabravo: I have already provided such a solution (see the last line of my answer), and I think that solution is better than the one you proposed because it ensures that every backslash is followed by another character. Otherwise, strings like `a\\xb` would not be split correctly.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>use this pattern, result is saved in sub-pattern #1</strike>

```
(?:\\x|xx)|(x)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/75)

OK, this could be done in two steps:
step 1: use this pattern `(\G.*?[^x\\](?:\\x|xx)*)x(?!x)` w/ `gms` options
and replace w/ something like `$1<SPLIT HERE>`
step 2: perform a split on this pattern `<SPLIT HERE>`
[Demo1](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/78)

or option #2:
use this pattern `(\G.*?[^x\\](?:\\x|xx)*)x(?!x)|(.*)` w/ `gm` options
and examine sub-patterns 1&2
[Demo2](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/79)

Comment: As I said in my question, the matched x is going to be used in a split function (like preg_split in php)... so using capturing / non capturing groups doesnt change anything in this case

Comment: Two steps seems to be an overkill... Check my third edit and thanks a lot for your interest <3